# Is »haben« always accusative or sometimes dative?

Tags: dative, accusative, declension-table

Why is dative in this sentence being used here?

> Dort saßen bereits fünf Jungs auf abgewetzten Sofas, alle barfuß und in kurzen Hosen. Drei von ihnen **hatten** Gitarren auf dem Schoß, aber nur einer spielte.

I thought that with »haben« one would use accusative.

Comment: Noun declension table.

Comment: Feminine plural column, to be exact.

Comment: Not everything that governs a case is a verb. The "dem" belongs to "Schoß", which is governed by "auf", which is a preposition. "haben" doesn't enter into it.

Answer (score 5):

Let's analyze that sentence.

> Drei von ihnen hatten Gitarren auf dem Schoß.

- **Drei von ihnen** – topic, subject, nominative, including a preposition+dative determiner *von ihnen*
- **hatten** – finite verb, preterite 3rd person plural of *haben*
- **Gitarren** – accusative object to *haben*
- **auf dem Schoß** – adverbial of place, preposition+dative

Answer (score 3):

What dative?  "Gitarren" as the object of "hatten" is accusative.

Comment: Please visit the help center, so you are informed and can profit the community more and profit from it, too.